# Compilation Errors while building minioozie

Tags: apache, maven, hadoop, oozie

I'm new to oozie and\ trying to install minioozie to test the workflows in oozie. I tried to follow the steps present in apache site http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/ENG_MiniOozie.html

I did the following steps:

git clone git://github.com/apache/oozie.git

**mvn clean install -DskipTests -DtestJarSimple -X**

The above statement fails with compile errors.

Stack Trace:

```
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/target/test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[56,43] cannot find symbol
symbol: class ActionExecutorTestCase
public class TestPigActionExecutor extends ActionExecutorTestCase {
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[119,12] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[138,36] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[77,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable super
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[74,4] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[82,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable super
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[83,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setSystemProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[80,4] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[91,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertEquals(java.util.List<java.lang.Class>,java.util.List<java.lang.Class>)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[94,34] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getJobTrackerUri()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[95,32] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getNameNodeUri()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[102,54] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getTestUser()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[105,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method createBaseWorkflow(org.apache.oozie.util.XConfiguration,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[109,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[109,30] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[112,53] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFsTestCaseDir()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[113,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[114,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[115,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[116,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[122,24] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[125,54] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getTestUser()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[128,55] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFsTestCaseDir()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[128,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable SharelibUtils
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[130,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method createBaseWorkflow(org.apache.oozie.util.XConfiguration,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[135,19] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[143,28] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[144,26] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[149,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertNotNull(java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[150,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertNotNull(java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[151,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertNotNull(java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[160,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getTestGroup()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[168,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertNotNull(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RunningJob)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[174,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[178,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[180,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method sleep(int)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[215,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[218,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[221,30] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getTestUser()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[222,76] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[224,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[231,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[233,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertNotNull(java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[237,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[241,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[245,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[255,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[258,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[265,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[267,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertNotNull(java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[268,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertNotSame(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[270,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[281,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setSystemProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[285,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[288,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[297,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[298,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertNull(java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[307,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[310,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[313,30] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getTestUser()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[314,76] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[316,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertFalse(boolean)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[323,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[324,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertNotNull(java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[328,32] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Predicate
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[334,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method sleep(int)
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[357,24] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[359,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAppPath()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[364,33] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFsTestCaseDir()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[365,34] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFsTestCaseDir()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[373,34] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getJobTrackerUri()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[374,32] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getNameNodeUri()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[385,24] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[387,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFsTestCaseDir()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[388,50] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getTestCaseDir()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[390,26] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[393,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAppPath()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[398,33] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFsTestCaseDir()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[399,34] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFsTestCaseDir()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[407,34] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getJobTrackerUri()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[408,32] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getNameNodeUri()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[424,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFsTestCaseDir()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[427,40] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAppPath()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[427,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[429,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[432,40] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAppPath()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[432,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[434,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[437,40] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAppPath()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[437,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[439,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[442,40] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAppPath()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[442,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[444,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[447,40] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAppPath()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[447,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[449,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFileSystem()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[452,40] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getJobTrackerUri()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[453,38] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getNameNodeUri()
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/skreddy/oozie/sharelib/pig/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/TestPigActionExecutor.java:[469,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.TestPigActionExecutor
[INFO] 100 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ................................. SUCCESS [1.150s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... SUCCESS [4.165s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT .... SUCCESS [0.233s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.1.1.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT  SUCCESS [0.184s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT Test  SUCCESS [0.283s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.2.0.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT .... SUCCESS [0.418s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.2.0.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT Test  SUCCESS [0.336s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.2.0.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT  SUCCESS [0.170s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT ... SUCCESS [0.340s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT Test  SUCCESS [0.310s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 0.23.5.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT  SUCCESS [0.181s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................... SUCCESS [0.063s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase 0.94.2.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT .... SUCCESS [0.181s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase Libs ........................... SUCCESS [0.044s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.5.0.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT .. SUCCESS [0.308s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.6.0.oozie-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT .. SUCCESS [0.282s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog Libs ........................ SUCCESS [0.069s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................... SUCCESS [1.256s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog ................... SUCCESS [0.553s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ................................. SUCCESS [18.624s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ................................. SUCCESS [0.619s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ........................ FAILURE [0.386s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SKIPPED
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs with both oozie.4.0.0 and oozie.4.0.1
Apparently, the core test-jar (oozie-core-4.0.0-tests.jar) does not include all the needed classes. Adding a few classes in the core/pom.xml solved the problem:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/XFsTestCase.class</include>
                    <include>**/XTestCase.class</include>
                    <include>**/XTestCase$*.class</include>
                    <include>**/Mini*.class</include>
                    <include>**/MainTestCase.class</include>
                    <include>**/SharelibUtils.class</include>
                    <include>**/ActionExecutorTestCase.class</include>
                    <include>**/ActionExecutorTestCase$Context.class</include>
                    <include>**/MapperReducer*Test.class</include>
                    <include>**/LauncherMainTester.class</include>
                    <include>**/Test*ActionExecutor.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: May be some users still get error for example like -"14/05/14 18:29:25 WARN datanode.DataNode: Invalid directory in dfs.data.dir: 
Incorrect permission for build/test/data/dfs/data/data1, 
expected: rwxr-xr-x, while actual: rwxrwxr-x" for that use "umask 022"

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug in Maven with JDK7: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-158 Try to increase your `maven-compiler-plugin` to `3.1`

You can see in the `pom.xml` that they use version `2.3.2`. They set the Java version to 1.6 but maybe it is not enough.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.2</version>
</plugin>
```